# prevent race condition in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, race-condition

I build firebase cloud function with global variable that increment the answer into object.
the issue is that I'm looking a way to prevent condition, when same users try to increment the variable in same time.

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');


// global variable 
let answers = {'a':0, 'b':0,'c':0}

exports.tryGetCount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body)
    let userAnswer = req.body.answer;
    let userInformation = req.body.userInfo;
    if(answers.hasOwnProperty(userAnswer)){
        answers[userAnswer]++; // increment the answer 
        return res.send({answers:answers})
    }
    return res.status(400).json({error:'invalid answer propertu'})




});
```

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as a truly "global" variable in Cloud Functions.  Your function may be executed by multiple server instance, each of which will have its own "global" variable.  If you want all your function invocations to share some data, you need some centralized location for that data.  For Firebase projects, this is typically Realtime Database or Firestore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-- Instead of using a global variable, make use of transaction

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

```js
var ref = new Firebase('xxx');

var countRef = ref.child("ans").child("-KGb1Ls-gEErWbAMMnZC").child('count');

countRef.transaction(function(currentCount) {
   return currentCount + 1;
});
```